# HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, h2

I'm running an integration test in WildFly 10 and when the server starts, there's a warning about the H2 database version:

> HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work.

Can anybody tell me how to precise the H2 version ? Thanks.

---

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="jsr352" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>org.hibernate.search.jsr352.test.entity.Company</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
      <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="ram" />
      <property name="hibernate.search.indexing_strategy" value="manual" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The subsystem datasources in WF **standalone.xml** configuration.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
  <datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
      <driver>h2</driver>
      <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password>sa</password>
      </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
      <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
      </driver>
    </drivers>
  </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: [WFLY-2325](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2325): this seems to be a rejected issue of WildFly.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue when I specified to use `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` when I in fact was using HSQL with driver `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver`. After changing to use `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` the message went away.

This is not the case for you, you seems to use H2 so maybe the driver class is wrong? I would expect something like:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
```